# How to echo the name of a file from code in an included file

Tags: php, filenames

I want to return the name of the *first* file being processed in the stack.

Let me explain: I've got two files.

1) `foo`:

> include("bar");

2) `bar`:

> echo __ FILE__;

When I request foo it displays "/home/example/bar" while I'd like to see the string "/home/example/foo" happening.

How to do that?

Comment: check the backtrace, it will have the first file in stack IIRC. - http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: Is this code meant to run on the command line or in a web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__FILE__` constant by design is ALWAYS the file where the constant appears, regardless of what file(s) have loaded/included this file. Try `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$backtrace = debug_backtrace();
echo $backtrace[0]['file'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
```